# Libraries/Solutions for using XSL to create interactive web forms from XML

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, xslt

This seems like a pretty straightforward thing to do, but I can't find anything off the open-source shelf.

Is there a solution already out there that does the following:

- can be configured with an arbitrary XSL stylesheet
- generates a web form based on an arbitrary XML document and the XSL
- creates edit functionality in appropriate places in the rendered form
- updates the local representation of the XML document
- provides capabilities to view, save the new XML document

Ideally, one that plugs into a Java web application. Even better if it can generate the XSL based on schema documents - but that might not be feasible, not really thought it through.

For context, I'm thinking things like pleasant-for-humans editing of Maven POMs, ANT build.xml, etc.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSL is meant to transform an XML into another XML, not to build interactive editors. What you want is an XML editor.

Also, editing XML via drag'n'drop or by clicking buttons and filling out popup dialogs will be very tedious.

Most modern XML editors work like normal text editors but they offer type-ahead and code completion plus an overview and short code templates. If you want to build something like that for the web, read up on AJAX and start with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) as your editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Xopus](http://xopus.com) is a web based XML editor which allows you to define interactive WYSIWYG views using (arbitrary) XSL. It is designed for 'pleasant-for-humans' editing.

It does not generate XSL based on XSD, but it does require an (arbitrary) XSD to drive the GUI and insert options. It can be easily configured to save back to a Java webapp. The [download](http://xopus.com/download.html) includes examples for that.

Disclaimer: I work at Xopus.